# Write to a relative text file. Java

Tags: java, text, text-files, filewriter, bufferedwriter

When trying to write to a text file that is relative I either create a new text file that is useless or I am just unable to write to it.
Right now I am doing this.

```
String file = new File("").toURI().relativize(new File(Launcher.class.getResource("/Account.txt").toString()).toURI()).getPath();
```

And

```
BufferedWriter outputStream = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                                new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
```

The errors are

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/Users/MyName/Folder/Folder2/Folder3/Launcher/bin/Account.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:104)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:184)
    at Launcher$Account.actionPerformed(Launcher.java:382)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

However the directory it says doesn't exist is the correct directory.

Comment: Wow, that is a lot of work just to obtain a relative file name.  What do you want your filename to be relative to?  If you want it to be relative to the current directory, you should just use `new File("Account.txt")`.

Comment: The thing is, is that if I do it that way, it ends up making the jar file need the txt file in the same folder as it. But by making it relative the text file will be in the jar file from the start.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "relative."  Relative to what?  Relative to a particular directory?  Relative to the application .class files?  Embedded inside the application's .jar file?

Comment: If you print or examine the value returned by `Launcher.class.getResource` when running from a .jar, you will see that the URL is not a `file:` URL and cannot be converted to a java.io.File instance.  Application resources returned by Class.getResource are not writable.

Comment: Allright. But is there a way to make it writable through parsing it?

Comment: No, but you can copy its contents to a temporary file or a file in a user configuration directory, and write it there.